# Why will my ModelState.AddModelError work before await HttpClient.PostAsync() but not after?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, modelstate

I am working on a project that has an aspnet core web app setup for my frontend along with an aspnet core web API for my backend. I am currently working on a login screen and all is going well except for Adding ModelError's. I have a model error that gets fired if the email is not able to be parsed. (So incorrect formatting). Then I want to have the same one be able to be fired if the password is incorrect. This is where my problem arises. The email verify works perfectly. But when I try to fire the one stating the password is wrong, then it doesn't show in my view.

```
public async void OnPost(UserDataModel model)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Email : {0}\nPassword : {1}", model.Email, model.Password));
        
        //This works if the email is not parsable
        if (isValidEmail(model.Email) == false) {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("loginError", "Login Error. Please verify your login credentials and try again!"); 
            return;
        }
       
        string receivedContent;
     

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator; //This is just for testing while in development

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", "0263afb0-0347-460c-8778-9dc429fc9063");

            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(content, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");


            var task = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("https://192.168.7.235:5003/Login"), stringContent);
            receivedContent = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        //Quotes surround the response but this removes it. This if block fires for sure based on the Console.Writeline
        if (receivedContent.Replace("\"", "") == "PasswordNotValid") 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Update model state");
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("loginError", "Login Error. Please verify your login credentials and try again!");
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
I have moved around my ModelState update method. It seems to only work when it is before the `await httpClient.PostAsync()` method. Hopefully this helps answer my question because I am not super familiar with async methods.

Comment: there's no return

Comment: I tried that. The first one works without a return but breaks because it sends an invalid email to my backend.